# Npgsql does not work properly, when using PGPOOL cluster

Tags: npgsql

My issue details are as follows,

Working Environment

- Npgsql = 3.0.7
- Entity Framework = 6.1.3
- PGPOOL = 3.5.2
- Postgres = 9.4.8

When querying database the following error occurs frequently (exception may vary time to time & place of occurrence).

> ERROR System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlBuffer.Ensure(Int32 count)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

or:

> ERROR System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlBuffer.Ensure(Int32 count)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadSingleMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean returnNullForAsyncMessage)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpectingT
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ExecuteInternalCommand(FrontendMessage message, Boolean withTimeout)
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Commit()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)

Same query run without pgpool, dose not get the above exception.

Can you please advice me to solve this issue?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate of https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1060, which has already been fixed. Try using the very new 3.1.0 to see if it solves your problems (watch out, it may be a bit raw), or wait until 3.0.8 comes out - it will contain the fix as well.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your soon response. For our future plans, may I know when it will be release the 3.0.8 or compatible EntityFramework6.Npgsql for 3.1.0? thank you.

Comment: EF6.Npgsql for 3.1.0 will be released in a few days, 3.0.8 will probably take a couple of weeks

Comment: Thanks. waiting for next EF6.Npgsql release.